# Hibernate Search - Lucene Filter exact match behaving oddly

Tags: hibernate, search, indexing, lucene, hibernate-search

I seem to miss some detail when filtering.

In my application I have a seminar offered by an institute. The institute should only see the seminars it offers. I therefore want to match the institute string of the seminar with a filter:

```
new TermFilter( new Term("institute", institute) );
```

and

```
instituteSeminarFullTextQuery.enableFullTextFilter( Seminar.SEMINAR_INSTITUTE_FILTER ).setParameter( "institute", institute );
```

the field is annotated as follows

```
@Basic
@Field(index = Index.YES, analyze = Analyze.NO, store = Store.NO)
private String institute;
```

This only works if I use "real words" as institute name, i.e. words from the dictionary. But the institute is often something like inst-1 or inst-2 in which case I get results from the other institute.

My guess would be that the Lucene index mangles the institute name and matches more than it should.

**How do I correctly retrieve results with an exact match?**

Comment: That sounds odd. Lucene should not "mangle" anything. Since you are using 'Analyze.NO' institute names should be indexed as is. How does your full query look like and can you give a concrete example of the data your are indexing and what results you get. You can also inspect the index to see what gets indexed. For this you probably want to use Store.YES, so that the indexed terms are actually stored in the index.

Comment: It seems like the problem solved itself. I can't reproduce it anymore. My only guess would be that after I turned off Analyze, the Lucene index didn't get updated and still returned old results.